# For loop that takes input file is not working

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, for-loop

I have a file containing two directory paths (will contain more). I want to read in each line and then do `ls` on each line. Pretty simple right?

The thing is that is not working and I do not know why. No matter what I do, the last line is always good with `ls`. The lines before are "non" existent to `ls`, even though they exist.

file.list

```
/path/to/directory1/
/path/to/directory2/
/path/to/directory1/
/path/to/directory2/
```

When I run the following snippet

```
DIRECTORIES="file.list"
for DIR2 in `cat $DIRECTORIES`
do
       echo $DIR2
       ls $DIR2
done
```

I get the following as output

```
/path/to/directory1/
 does not exist. file /path/to/directory1/
/path/to/directory2/
 does not exist. file /path/to/directory2/
/path/to/directory1/
 does not exist. file /path/to/directory1/
/path/to/directory2/
Server
```

What is wrong with it? Any other better solution?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Strange, I just tried it in another Unix box and works just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be $DIR2 contain line endings? Try to remove them:

```
DIR2=`echo $DIR2 | tr -d '\r'`
```

I think so because posted log looks very strange for me. `ls` command's output on my pc looks like:

`ls: cannot access /path/to/directory1/: No such file or directory`

But your's:

```
 does not exist. file /path/to/directory1/
```

Comment: the lines did have some strange character at the end of the line, by editing the file on a plain text editor I was able to remove then and worked. I tried using your method for removing `$DIR2=\`echo $DIR2 | tr -d '[\n\r]'\`` but did not work

Comment: I made a typo, sorry. Try to use updated line of code (without dollar sign on the left side). I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`cat` is an evil program, best is not to use it. You must read your file line by line, `cat` output is not line buffered.

```
while read path ; do
    ls $path
done <file.list
```

Comment: `cat` is not evil, though it is (quite often) misused.

Comment: Cat is not useless, but it is often used when it is not needed.

Comment: This one works too, but is not getting the last line, just the first three lines.

Comment: @JGeZau Ok, you caught me finally. In your file the last line doesn't have the linefeed, and bash's `read` considers that not as a complete line.

Answer (score 0):

JGeZau,

The script looks fine, have you checked that you're referencing your paths correctly in terms of absolute / relative?.

I've copied your script in bash and I had no problems at all:

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTORIES="paths"
for DIR2 in `cat $DIRECTORIES`
do
   echo $DIR2
   ls $DIR2
done
```

paths:

```
/var/logs/
/var/tmp/
```

output:

./test.sh

```
/var/logs/
file1.log file2.log 

/var/tmp/
tmp1 tmp2 tmp3
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Strange, I just tried it in another Unix box and works just fine